# R: Converting a data frame into a matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix written to a [csv file](http://1drv.ms/1N776wH).

[image]

I'm trying to read the file and get the data as a matrix. I have used as.matrix and data.matrix functions. However I'm unable to load the data as a matrix. 
My goal is to use this distance matrix for hierarchical clustering.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can use `read.csv` to read the `.csv` file, set the first column as row names (`row.names=1`), and converting to `matrix` (`as.matrix`) should work fine.

```
  d1 <- read.csv('Test_Matrix.csv', row.names=1)
  m1 <- as.matrix(d1)
  m1
  #  A B C D
  #A 0 1 2 3
  #B 1 0 4 5
  #C 2 4 0 6
  #D 3 5 6 0
  is.matrix(m1)
  #[1] TRUE
```

Or as @RHertel mentioned in the comments, we can combine both in a single step

```
  as.matrix(read.csv('Test_Matrix.csv', row.names=1))
```

Comment: @RHertel Thanks, but without the `row.names` it will have an extra column and the output will be 'character'  columns